# load file with csv extension in ssis

Tags: sql, csv, flat-file, ssis-2008, flatfilesource

I have to load file with csv extension from one particular folder to data base in ssis. file name is not known but folder and extension is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

To load the content of a file, the file name with folder path is required else the connection manager can not be validated and configured.

The easiest way is to get file name is using a For Each Loop container:

1. Select the option [Foreach File Enumerator]
2. Provide the Folder path and extension (like *.csv) you already have.
3. Get the File Name in a variable and use it within the Source of the data flow task within the For each Loop container.

[Refer](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/803195/Foreach-File-Enumerator-in-SSIS)